# How to check whether parent class implements child class interface in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, class, inheritance, interface

I have 2 classes `Student` and `Teacher` and one interface `ICanOperate`. The child class `Student` implements the interface `ICanOperate`. How to check whether the super class `Teacher` implements the interface as well?

```kotlin
open class Teacher(
    var name: String,
    var registry: Int,
    internal var phoneNumber: String
){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return ("$name, $registry, $phoneNumber")
    }
}

class Student(name : String, registry : Int, phoneNumber : String , var badgeNumber : String) : ICanOperate , Teacher (name, registry , phoneNumber)  {
    override fun OperateClass(): String {
        return "Book please"
    }
    override fun toString(): String {
        return ("$name ($registry) - $phoneNumber Badge : $badgeNumber" );
    }
}

interface ICanOperate {
    fun OperateClass () : String;
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var obj = Student("Ash", 157, "9029897581", "B00894354")
    var obj3 = Teacher("Elon", 1232, "9029893188")
   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to check whether the super class Teacher implements the interface as well?

It doesn't. We know it from the code: `Teacher` doesn't implement the interface.

However, I think what you meant is "how to check whether some instance of `Teacher` happens to be of a class that does implement the interface?".

In that case, you can do it simply using an `is` check:

```kotlin
if (someTeacher is ICanOperate) {
    // do something
}
```